# SQL to get all data for the last 30 days from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

How can I write an SQL to get all the data from a specified table for the last 30 days without having to manually specify the date? I have a table as follows:

```
school
(
  school_id bigint,school_name character varying(100),
  school_code character varying(10),
  created_time timestamp with time zone,
)
```

I am trying to get all records whose `created_time` is in the last 30 days. 
I am trying something like the following, but it is not working for me:

```
select * from school where created_time > '2017-09-31 11:12:57.425+00';
```

Also, I do not want to manually specify the date, I want to get data for the last 30 days by getting the current date automatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

The current error I am getting is as follows:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2017-09-31 11:12:57.425+00"
LINE 1: select * from school where created_time > '2017-09-31...
                                                         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2017-09-31 11:12:57.425+00"
SQL state: 22008
Character: 50
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `current_timestamp` (documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)):

```
select *
from school
where created_time > current_timestamp - interval '30 day';
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks, I am trying to pull out few more date from another table like below: select s.school_name, s.user_created, u.email, u.first_name
from school s, ugrp_user u
where subscription_term = 'trial' and s.user_created = u.user_id and created_time > current_timestamp - interval '30 day'; But this gives me an error as: 
ERROR: column reference "created_time" is ambiguous. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: First, *never* use comma in the `from` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `join` syntax.  Second, new questions should be asked as new questions, not as comments.  Third, always qualify column names when you have more than one table reference in a query.

Comment: @thanks Gordon Linoff, let me try to figure that out